# Canonical quantization - can't form creation or annilhation operators?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, second-quantization

This question is related to this [PSE question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/350053/free-complex-scalar-field-showing-operators-are-creation-and-annihlation) I asked yesterday. From this question and what I have read, the general procedure for canonical quantization is as follows (correct me if I am wrong):

1. Write down the Lagrangian.
2. Solve the Euler-Lagrange equations to get the field (which may be a scalar, vector or tensor field) in terms of arbitrary operators e.g. $\hat a_i$, $\hat b_i$, $\hat c_i$ and $\hat d_i$.
3. Find the commutators of $\hat a_i$, $\hat b_i$, $\hat c_i$ and $\hat d_i$ by using the CCRs or CARs.
4. Define the vacuum and higher states in such away that $\hat a_i$, $\hat b_i$, $\hat c_i$ and $\hat d_i$ are creation and annihilation operators.
5. Find the Hamiltonian etc.

My question is; is it always true the (4) can be done? What for example if the commutators in step (3) don't lead to the typical creation and annihilation commutators? If the answer is no how do we go about defining the states?

<sub><sup>Edit: For future reference (for me or anyone else who stumbles on this question): http://theory.fi.infn.it/casalbuoni/lezioni99.pdf (page 9) gives the steps of canonical quantization.</sup></sub>

Comment: Notice that the quantisation procedure in terms of creation/annihilation operators on the Fock space only works for linear "simple" fields: in the general case one can show that the full Fock space isn't always well defined (at any time $t$) and the solutions of the equations cannot always be expressed in Fourier transform (at any time $t$). The general "quantisation" procedure is done in physics by using the path integral quantisation.

Comment: @gennaro tedasco: but doesn't the path integral suffer from a similar problem; ie it's not rigorously well-defined?

Comment: The path integral suffers from many other problems, which are however different from the one you raised. It does solve your problem, although at the cost of a difficult-to-define rigorous approach in other areas.

Comment: @gennaro tedasco: ok, I see; it's a kind of trade-off.

Comment: @GennaroTedesco Do you know any good sources that explains this? I am struggling to find anything rigorous on even the simple fields.

Comment: @GennaroTedesco In order for a quantum theory to make sense – we have to have a Hilbert space (or a Gelfand triple) with self-adjoint operators acting on it corresponding to physical observables. In come cases it is nice to represent some of these operators with path integrals. Path integrals should only be considered complementory to the quantum formalism. I believe that OP's concern is an actual problem (and a well-known one; e.g. formulating a well-defined Yang-Mills theory is one of the problems of the unsolved Millenium prize problems, I believe). Do you disagree with this?

Comment: @SolenodonParadoxus  I disagree: your statement is valid for quantum mechanics, but not for quantum field theory. In the former self-adjoint operators acting on the Hilbert space represent the observables: in the latter the observables are the correlation functions and propagators. The Hilbert space is required to carry a representation of the Poincaré group with a unique ground state left invariant by the action of the (positive energy) unitary representations of the invariant groups of the theory (plus some other Wightman axioms).

Comment: *"... In some cases it is nice to represent some of these operators with path integrals..."* path integrals **are not** representations of operators, they are path integrals and that's it. *"...Path integrals should only be considered complementory to the quantum formalism..."* no, path integrals generate the correlation functions: how would you calculate them otherwise (we assume we aren't in the framework of Algebraic QFT where one assigns the correlations and then derives back the whole theory)?

Comment: *"I believe that OP's concern is an actual problem (and a well-known one; e.g. formulating a well-defined Yang-Mills theory is one of the problems of the unsolved Millenium prize problems, I believe)"* I don't see how the question (canonical quantisation with creation and annihilation operators) relates to Yang-Mills theories.

Comment: @GennaroTedesco "how would you calculate them otherwise" – pretty simple, actually. Time-ordered expectation functions of renormalized field operators sandwiched between renormalized vacuum states. That's it. And before you say that we can't actually calculate this without perturbation theory, remember that the same is true for path integrals.

Comment: @GennaroTedesco "your statement is valid for quantum mechanics, but not for quantum field theory" QFT is an application of Quantum Mechanics to the field-theoretic models. It does run into some nonstandard issues like nonseparability of the Hilbert space etc, but those aren't particularly related to the topic we are currently discussing.

Comment: @GennaroTedesco "path integrals are not representations of operators, they are path integrals and that's it" most of QFT textbook authors would disagree.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63353/discussion-between-solenodon-paradoxus-and-gennaro-tedesco).